# Optimization of numpy array values change

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, image-size

I wrote this piece of code to change pixels values of an image as such :

```
def px_values_label(img, rgb_list):
    # Change pixel values according to the rgb color code
    # for further shape remodeling (one hot encoding)

    for number, rgb in enumerate(rgb_list):
        mask = (img == rgb).all(axis=3)
        img[mask] = [number,0,0]

    img = rgb2gray(img)

    for w in range(1,len(rgb_list)):
        img[img == w*0.2989] = w
    img[img > len(rgb_list)] = 0

    return img


# The input image only contains these RGB trios (like in here: [image])[1]  
rgb_list = [[7,13,95], [14,245,33], [3,89,10], [64,135,207], [205,24,54]]

image = np.array(Image.fromarray("very_large_image.tif"))

altered_img = px_values_label(image, rgb_list)
```

The function takes an array (`img`) and a list of RGB values (such as `rgb_list = [[13,41,22],[76,32,139],[29,234,197]]`. The function flattens the image into greyscale and change the RGB values to 0,1,2,3... (according to the len of RGB list provided).

The code works for small images and provides me the right result. However, must I play with very big images `(12000x12000)` ending up in a crash and it takes a long time to process.

Does anyone have an idea to optimize the function ?

Regards

Comment: You should create a numpy array, as you mentioned in the headline. Your current code does not use numpy at all. Even with numpy, this will be probably slow, but without it won't work at all.

Comment: Sorry, maybe it wasn't clear enough. The img is a numpy array !

Comment: Can you share enough code/data that we can run the program ourselves? Please see: [mcve].

Comment: You realize the first element of your `rgb_list` is going to be mapped to `0`, just like everything out of the list.  Right?

Comment: [Labelled comprehension](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.measurements.labeled_comprehension.html) could be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for you answers.
@DanielF Why would everything be mapped to 0 ?

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem How would you use this Labelled_comprehension ?